# Python print variable not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python

i have a piece of code that just prints a username from a json list and a password is randomly generated

`print ('sending username %s and password %s' % username, password)`

But i get the following error:

```
        print ('sending username %s and password %s' % username, password)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: `print ('sending username %s and password %s' % (username, password))`?

Answer (score 0):

`print ('sending username %s and password %s' % username, password)` means:

> call `print` with two arguments:
>
> - `'sending username %s and password %s' % username`
> - `password`

The first string doesn't get enough formatting arguments (one instead of two). You meant to use a *tuple*:

```
'sending username %s and password %s' % (username, password)
```